# session_set_cookie_params seems to work but cookies are not affected

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm using HTTPS and I would like to set the secure attribute for the `PHPSESSID` and the other `cookies` I have created.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]));
session_start();
$data = session_get_cookie_params();
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.$value;
}
```

The function seems to work, in fact, printing out `session_get_cookie_params()` the secure attribute  is equal to 1.
But, when I check my cookie state by `Firefox` or by `Firebug+Firecookie` they appear to be not affected at all by the statement. Even changing the domain attribute gives the same results.

I'm working on XAMPP, on Ubuntu and on localhost (localhost should have a special treatment for security issues, maybe).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Conan. I'm sorry for the names wrong format, but I'm a newbie...

Comment: u'r welcome, i'm just trying to help. btw have u tried it using http?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but results were exactly the same: it was only apparently set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `session name` when using `session_set_cookie_params`.

Reference:
[PHP session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
[PHP session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, I didn't notice that comment on the man page during my previous visits. Does session name have to be unique for each session?

Comment: well, it depend on your need. if you have another purpose to make a new session name than do it, if not then don't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and using session_name() didn't help. I had to disable session_start() generating the cookie and generate the cookie manually like this:

```
$sessionID = $_COOKIE[session_name()];
ini_set('session.use_cookies', false);
if ($sessionID) session_id($sessionID); // reuse if available
session_start();
// session_set_cookie_params() is not working with a "path" part
// this way every click is extending the session for $timeout more
setcookie(session_name(), $sessionID ?: session_id(), time() + $timeout, $cookiePath, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], false, true);
```

x-powered-by: PHP/5.4.15