# session_set_cookie_params prevents cookie from beeing set

Tags: php, session

I'm seetting a session cookie for a day and wanted to set the cookie timeout also.

```
// 1 day
define( 'COOKIE_TIMEOUT', 86400 );
ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', COOKIE_TIMEOUT );
session_set_cookie_params( COOKIE_TIMEOUT, '/');
```

But if I leave `session_set_cookie_params` in there, the cookie is not set.

What am I missing? Never happened before.

Here's the rest of the session code that follows afterwards

```
// set session dir
$sessdir = BASEDIR.'/data/sessions';
// create the session dir if it does not exist
if ( !is_dir( $sessdir ) ) {
    @mkdir( $sessdir, 0777 );
}
// if directory exists, then set session.savepath otherwise let it go as is
if( is_dir( $sessdir ) ) {
    ini_set( 'session.save_path', $sessdir );
}
session_start();
```

Comment: So if you use `session_set_cookie_params( COOKIE_TIMEOUT, '/');`, the cookie is never set, and if you remove it, it works? Is this correct?

Comment: yes that's correct. If I comment the function it is set with default lifetime

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117374/session-set-cookie-params-seems-to-work-but-cookies-are-not-affected